# Chained selectors in jQuery: apply selector in already filtered results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

IGNORE: http://jsfiddle.net/gulcoza/9cVFT/1/

**UPDATED FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/gulcoza/9cVFT/4/

The whole code is in the above fiddle, but I will explain here also:

`HTML`

```
<ul>
    <li id="e1">1</li>
    <li id="e2" class="hidden">2</li>
    <li id="e3">3</li>
    <li id="e4" class="hidden">4</li>
    <li id="e5">5</li>
    <li id="e6">6</li>
    <li id="e7">7</li>
    <li id="e8">8</li>
    <li id="e9">9</li>
    <li id="e10">10</li>
</ul>
```

`jQuery`

```
console.log(
    $('ul li:visible:nth-child(4n)')
);
```

**My Expected result:** `li#e6, li#e10` - why? because I want the 4n elements only from the visible ones.

But

**Actual Result:** I get the 4n element from all only if they are visible.

```
console.log(
    $('ul li:visible').filter(function(index) {
        if ((index + 1) % 4 ==0) return true;
    })
);
```

I am interested in any nicer solution than the following one:

```
console.log(
    $('ul li:visible').filter(function(index) {
        if ((index + 1) % 4 ==0) return true;
    })
);
```

**UPDATED FIDDLE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/gulcoza/9cVFT/4/

Why doesn't number 4 work. At the moment filter is called the results should be filtered already, IMHO. :|

```
// 4 - could be a nice solution
console.log(
    $('ul li:visible').filter(':nth-child(4n)')
);
```

Why doesn't this work? At `$('ul li:visible')` moment only the visible one should be available.

Comment: `:nth-child` is with respect to the parent element, not to the selection. Your use of `filter` is the appropriate solution, although you may want to put the function elsewhere in code so that it can be reused if you're going to call it multiple times.

Comment: cant i group them using commas or anything.. couldn't find anything usefull on net

Comment: What is wrong with your solution? I think it is the best solution to this. Like @zzzzBov said, you should put the function somewhere to reuse.

Comment: @BillyMathews - I just can't make my peace.. and most important why isn't way no. 4 not working? check updated fiddle

Comment: @Pete - `:eq` or '.eq' method does Select the element at index n within the matched set. So only one. I need from 4 to 4

Comment: could you try `$('ul li:visible:odd:odd')`

Comment: @alex.dominte no.4 isn't working because `:nth-child` is still referring to the index of the element relative to it's parent. Remember - `:nth-child` is *CSS*, not jQuery.

Comment: @BillyMathews - thanks it does make sense now. PS: any documentation/reference on this difference between jquery-css selectors would be appreciated

Comment: Give me a min I'll write up an answer for you.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/2175772/2019222

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `nth-child` matches elements on the basis of their positions within a parent element’s list of child elements not on the basis of jQuery Collection (*selected elements*), in this you have to use `filter` method, `filter` method is also faster that chained-string selectors.

This is how the selectors filter the elements:

```
$('ul li:nth-child(4n):visible') 
//       ^            ^---- [li#e8]
//       |  
//       | --- [li#e4.hidden, li#e8]

$('ul li:visible:nth-child(4n)') 
//       ^            ^---- [li#e8]
//       |  
//       | --- [li#e1, li#e3, li#e5, li#e6, li#e7, li#e8, li#e9, li#e10]
//             [1,     3,     5,     6,     7,     8,     9,     10]
```

Comment: I understand this, but I can't understand why this is not working `console.log(
    $('ul li:visible').filter(':nth-child(4n)')
);` check updated question

Comment: @alex.dominte because the only ones that are :nth-child(4n) of the ul is either the 4th or the 8th li - the 4th one is hidden so all you get is the 8th li

Comment: any documentation/reference on this difference between jquery-css selectors would be appreciated

Comment: @alex.dominte You are welcome, `nth-child` on [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Comment: "`nth-child` is not cross-browser" how so? [jQuery makes it work in every browser](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/). As a CSS selector it may not work, but within jQuery it always will.

Comment: @zzzzBov Yes, I was wrong, edited the answer. jQuery provides support for it if it's not supported by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

As you now know - the best way to do this is your way.

The reason this was not working as you expected is because the `:nth-child` pseudo selector is selecting elements based on their position within the parent element.

Note also that the selector string is a string of *CSS* selectors, and are not to do with JavaScript.

I found a good answer on another question about JS/CSS [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8830881/1879895)

I would suggest you create your own method like this:

```
$.fn.nthChildren = function(n){
    this.filter(function(index) {
        if ((index + 1) % n ==0) return true;
    })
}
console.log(
    $('ul li:visible').nthChildren(4);
);
```